# Springfox Swagger ignores @XmlElement for nested objects only

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, swagger, springfox

I'm using springfox 3.0.0 and my XML Swagger looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Foo>
    <anotherBar>
        <MyStr>string</MyStr>
    </anotherBar>
    <bar>
        <MyStr>string</MyStr>
    </bar>
    <MyDate>2021-10-08T16:08:57.795Z</MyDate>
</Foo>
```

Here is what I would like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Foo>
    <AnotherBar>
        <MyStr>string</MyStr>
    </AnotherBar>
    <Bar>
        <MyStr>string</MyStr>
    </Bar>
    <MyDate>2021-10-08T16:08:57.795Z</MyDate>
</Foo>
```

As you can see, `MyStr` and `MyDate` are displayed correctly in the XML but not `bar` and `anotherBar` without the uppercase.

I don't know why the `@XmlElement` annotation is ignored by Springfox for nested objects only. But it works great with `String` or `Instant`.

Here is my `Foo` class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Foo")
public class Foo {
    @XmlElement(name = "MyDate")
    private Instant myDate;

    @XmlElement(name = "Bar")
    private Bar bar;

    @XmlElement(name = "AnotherBar")
    private Bar anotherBar;

    // Getter / Setter...
}
```

And here is my `Bar` class:

```
public class Bar {

    @XmlElement(name = "MyStr")
    private String myStr;

    // Getter / Setter ...

}
```

Here is my `XmlMapper` config:

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
```

I already tried to replace `@XmlElement` with `@JacksonXmlProperty` but it's the same result.

I found also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64562167 but I don't want to use `@JsonProperty` since I need the JSON from Swagger to use attributes name.

Do you know why `@XmlElement` is ignored by Springfox in this case only?

Comment: What happens if you add `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)` to the class `Foo` ? With that annotation only fields actually annotated will be considered.

Comment: @k5_ I tried to add `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)` to the class `Foo` but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: `Springfox` is dead, use `springdoc-openapi` instead. We migrated and a lot of long unsolved problems disappeared. Try it and if your problem persist, solve it only after. See e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58953513/2886891

Comment: @honza-zidek I also tried with springdoc instead of springfox. There is also the exact same thing. However, the `@Schema` annotation works to rename a field with springdoc, but I want to rename only the field for the XML media type and not the JSON. And the `@Schema` annotation renames both in the same time.